# Google script: Trying to copy multiple cell values to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, constants

The code works only for D2:D6. I would like to copy more cell values to Database.
If I add another line like this:   `const data = sh1.getRange('D2:D6').getValues();`
It gives an error.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Nieuw'); 
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
 
  const data = sh1.getRange('D2:D6').getValues();

  sh2.getRange(1,sh2.getLastColumn()+1,data.length,1).setValues(data); 
}
```

Comment: You need to 1. Show how you modified your script 2. Quote the exact error that was thrown 3. Show your search efforts on searching that error.

Comment: You can not redefine a `const`.

Comment: I didn't modify the script.  It does not give an error. It only copies the first range and not the second etc. I would like to copy more ranges. No need to search for the error code. I searched for the solluction but no luck.

Comment: The post said that when you added something it gave an error... you should add that error textually. Anyway, please spend some time learning about variables in JavaScript. This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables

Comment: Apps script = Javascript with apps script methods to interact with google products. I suggest you learn javascript, maybe at freecodecamp.org

Comment: Follow a bunch of videos from [this](https://www.youtube.com/c/LearnGoogleSpreadsheets) channel

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0'); 
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = sh1.getRange('D2:H' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  sh2.getRange(1,sh2.getLastColumn()+1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); 
}
```